# Querying with limit and offset, is there a chance to have different results with the same query in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Base on the Postgres documentation offset is:

> OFFSET says to skip that many rows before beginning to return rows.

Having considered that, I wonder if the default sorting/no sorting logic on the sql query has an effect on it, is there a chance to get different results with the same query when using the default sorting?

Comment: What is "default sorting"?  I've never heard of any such thing.

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant a query without any sorting added to it. ie. Select * from table;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OFFSET` and `LIMIT` are applied as the final step in query processing, actually when the result set is being returned from the query.

If the query does not have an `ORDER BY`, then the results of the query are in an *indeterminate* order. And, in fact, the ordering of the results can vary from one run of the query to the next.

Even with an `ORDER BY`, you an get indeterminate orders -- when rows have the same key values. Sorting in SQL is not stable (a stable sort would always return rows in the same order). The reason is simple: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no "natural" ordering to define a stable sort.

If you care about consistently ordered data, then you should always use `ORDER BY`. And, you should be sure that the key combinations uniquely define each row. If they don't, throw in the primary key as the last key for the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as getting different results with default (meaning no order by) sure that will be based on how SQL optimizes the query from 1 run to the other but I would surmise that generally DML operations such as insert or delete will be the largest culprit of differentiating results.

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable (Id INTEGER, Letter CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO ExampleTable (Id,Letter) VALUES (1,'A'),(5,'C'),(3,'B');


SELECT *
FROM
    ExampleTable
ORDER BY 1    
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
;

SELECT 'Example 1' as Example, *
FROM
    ExampleTable
ORDER BY 1    
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;

INSERT INTO ExampleTable (Id, Letter) VALUES (2,'D');

SELECT *
FROM
    ExampleTable
ORDER BY 1    
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
;

SELECT 'Example 1' as Example, *
FROM
    ExampleTable
ORDER BY 1    
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

First Result is `3,b` second result is `2,D` Later when running this with an additional column I was getting `5,c & 5,C`.  PostresSQL is optimizing the query on the INTEGER when there is not an additional dedicated value.  So this causes the default (no order) to be different from query to query. [http://rextester.com/YJKC24018]

Now consider ordering by LETTER:

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable2 (Id INTEGER, Letter CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO ExampleTable2 (Id,Letter) VALUES (1,'A'),(3,'C'),(4,'D');

SELECT *
FROM
    ExampleTable2
ORDER BY Letter
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
;

INSERT INTO ExampleTable2 (Id,Letter) VALUES (2,'B');

SELECT *
FROM
    ExampleTable2
ORDER BY Letter
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
;
```

The first result will be `3,C` but the second result will be `2,B`.  So even though you have chosen offset because the record set changed you could get the same row or a new row [http://rextester.com/IBI93830]

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable3 (Id INTEGER, Letter CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO ExampleTable3 (Id,Letter) VALUES (1,'A'),(3,'C'),(4,'D');

SELECT *
FROM
    ExampleTable3
ORDER BY Letter
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
;

INSERT INTO ExampleTable3 (Id,Letter) VALUES (2,'B');

SELECT *
FROM
    ExampleTable3
ORDER BY Letter
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
;
```

So here is an example that a new record `(2,B)` was inserted before the last record you received `(3,C)` as a result.  So even though you incremented the OFFSET you will actually get the same row `(3,C)` again. [http://rextester.com/KRVIF54374]

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable4 (Id SERIAL, Letter CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO ExampleTable4 (Letter) VALUES ('A'),('C'),('D');

SELECT *
FROM
    ExampleTable4
ORDER BY Id
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
;

INSERT INTO ExampleTable4 (Letter) VALUES ('B');

SELECT *
FROM
    ExampleTable4
ORDER BY Id
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
;    

DELETE FROM ExampleTable4 WHERE Letter = 'C';

SELECT *
FROM
    ExampleTable4
ORDER BY Id
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
;
```

This example shows that order on ID you can stay consistent, except once a delete happens on the table now results have changed with the same query. [http://rextester.com/LTN10302]